# How to invoke powershell Set-Location command silently?

Tags: powershell

I would like to cd to some directory without the path to that directory being displayed by powershell. No matter what I try - nothing works:

```
PS C:\dev\windows\nc> cd .\NC.Server.Host | Out-Null
C:\dev\windows\nc\NC.Server.Host
PS C:\dev\windows\nc\NC.Server.Host> cd .. > $null
C:\dev\windows\nc
PS C:\dev\windows\nc> cd .\NC.Server.Host 2> $null
C:\dev\windows\nc\NC.Server.Host
PS C:\dev\windows\nc\NC.Server.Host> $x=cd ..
C:\dev\windows\nc
PS C:\dev\windows\nc>
```

As you can see the target directory path is always displayed. Is it a way to avoid it? Thanks.

**EDIT**

Here is my prompt function:

```
PS Z:\dev\3rd_party> gc Function:prompt
$(if (test-path variable:/PSDebugContext) { '[DBG]: ' } else { '' }) + 'PS ' + $(Get-Location) + $(if ($nestedpromptlevel -ge 1) { '>>' }) + '> '
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably use the PowerShell Community Extensions. In those `cd` is defined as an alias to `Set-LocationEx` which exhibits this behaviour:

```
PS Home:\> Set-Location ..
PS Home:\> Set-LocationEx ..
Home:\
```

Either use `Set-Location` instead of `cd`, or don't load PSCX or redefine `cd` to its usual alias after loading PSCX in your profile.

(Those are the reasons I load PSCX only occasionally if I actually need a command from there; redefining core commands or aliases with slightly different semantics is evil and should never be done.)

Comment: I have edited my post to point out the actual problem ;-). Sorry for the stab in the dark earlier.